# Polygamy in Islam

Tags: nikah, wife, polygamy

The conditions for having more than one wife as per my understanding are:-

- Treat all wives equally
- Provide all wives with the same standard of
  accommodation

If a man is able to meet all these conditions, then can he not have as many wives as he wants to? Why only limit to 4? Why only 4 wives are allowed in Islam?

Answer (score 1):

In Islam, we must obey the commands of Allah and His Messenger, even when the wisdom behind those commands or decrees are unknown to us.

We do not know why we must pray two rak'ahs in the Fajr prayer (rather than three or four, for example), but we know that this is the Decree of Allah and the practice of His Messenger. Likewise, we don't know why the number of wives a man can marry was limited to four, but we know that this was decreed by Allah and proclaimed by His Messenger.

Prior to Islam, there was no limit as to how many women a man could marry. One obvious problem with such system is that a small number of men (typically the richest or the most powerful) could marry all of the marriageable women in the town, and the rest of the men would have to remain single, as they could find no woman to marry.

Comment: you can add ﷺ when his name ﷺ is referred. 
البخيل من ذكرت عنده ولم يصلي علي
ﷺ

Comment: اللهم صلّ علی سيدنا محمد

Comment: اللهم صلّ علی سيدنا محمد

Comment: @SeekerTruth: Any ayat in the Quran that limits the number of wives?
A "small number of men (typically the richest or the most powerful) could marry all of the marriageable women in the town..", isn't this too much of a statement to make? Like ever heard that before Islam or in any era, the richest men married all the women of the town and left none for the common people?

Comment: The Quran is not the only source of islamic legislation. The ahadith are clear in prohibiting marrying more than four wives at the same time. The Prophet ﷺ told those who had more than four wives prior to their islam to choose four wives to keep, and to divorce the rest. https://dorar.net/hadith/sharh/134408
The point was such a situation is possible in theory; even if that extreme situation doesn't happy, it is likely that the number of unmarried men would rise. And Allah knows best.

Comment: @Ganit Yes, Quran 4:3